# Sharing interfaces between Typescript projects

Tags: angular, typescript, nestjs

I am developing two projects (an Angular client and a NestJS server) that at the end consume the same interfaces, let's say User, Product, etc..

I am looking for a way not to duplicate these interfaces files in both projects, but rather have a mutualised project hosting shared code and referenced by the server and the client projets that have their own building setup.

Would you have any hint ? Thanks !

Comment: Create another repository for declarations and types and consume this repo in both of your projects, using npm install.

Comment: You can either create a monorepo, and store all the shared interfaces in a package, or you can create a separate repo for the interfaces and export it as an NPM package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

establish a new "common" typescript library repository, home to all your system-wide interfaces and functionality. version and publish this common library to npm for easy access

then both the client and server projects should `npm install mycommonlibrary`

during local development, you should use `npm link` to develop and debug the common library, client, and server, all together simultaneously

**opinionated advice:** following the above pattern, i've found the following strategy useful: write all your app's "buisness logic" in the common library, and your mocks and testing code too -- this is very flexible: you can take, for example, what is normally your *serverside* business logic, but then run it on the *clientside,* wired up mocks of the database, so that you can exercise most of your system isomorphically like that, it's pretty neato

Comment: I followed this video that illustrates your suggestion https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jJNIuBTAb6Q thanks !

Answer (score 2):

I've just read an article about this case, I think it's gonna help with your problem,

In that article, they'll combine Angular and NestJS and learn how to take advantage of code sharing in a Nx monorepo ....
[sharing made easy in full-stack app with NX, angular and nestjs](https://indepth.dev/code-sharing-made-easy-in-a-full-stack-app-with-nx-angular-and-nestjs/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a single repository for both projects: I would define the shared interface in the server and use `import type` in the client.

And I would not share interfaces if it is not in a single repository.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to create a third project with all your common assets. You can refer its *.d.ts from both projects.